# How to extract specific 32 x 32 icon from EXE to a TIcon with Delphi

Tags: delphi, icons

My go is to extract only 32 x 32 size icon from EXE files. I'm new to image manipulation, but based on several examples found on Internet I got this code:

```
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
function PrivateExtractIcon(lpszFile: PChar; nIconIndex, cxIcon, cyIcon: Integer; phicon: PHANDLE; pIconId: PDWORD; nIcon, flags: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'PrivateExtractIconsW';
{$ELSE}
function PrivateExtractIcon(lpszFile: PChar; nIconIndex, cxIcon, cyIcon: Integer; phicon: PHANDLE; pIconId: PDWORD; nIcon, flags: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'PrivateExtractIconsA';
{$ENDIF}

function GetExeIcon(const Path: string; const Size: Integer; Icon: TIcon): Boolean;
var
  hIcon: THandle;
  hIconId: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  if PrivateExtractIcon(PChar(Path), 0, Size, Size,
    @hIcon, @hIconId, 1, LR_LOADFROMFILE) = 1 then
  try
    Icon.Handle := hIcon;
    Result := True;
  finally
    DestroyIcon(hIcon);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnGetIconClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Icon: TIcon;
begin
  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    if GetExeIcon(edtPath.Text, 32, Icon) then
      Icon.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'temp.ico');
  finally
    Icon.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This code result in the following error message:

> Bitmap image is not valid

When removing the line `DestroyIcon(hIcon);` from the function, it works. But than I have a memory leak.

Please, can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "*When removing the line `DestroyIcon(hIcon);` from the function, it works. But than I have a memory leak*" - no, you don't.  Setting the `TIcon.Handle` property takes *ownership* of the assigned `HICON` handle.  The `TIcon` destructor will destroy the `HICON` for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, excuse my ignorance. Please, include your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: How is `PrivateExtractIcon()` defined? The WinAPI only knows [`PrivateExtractIconsA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-privateextracticonsa). Keep in mind that EXE files can have 0 to many icons. An icon can have a 32x32 variant, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @AmigoJack, I updated the question to include `PrivateExtractIcon()` definition. And yes, I know EXE can have no 32x32 icon and even no icon at all. Thank you!

Comment: @Guybrush `PrivateExtractIcon()` remains undefined - you only imported `PrivateExtractIcons()`. The purpose of a [MRE] ist that you REALLY checked it first yourself.